# javascript [1,2,3,4] becomes 12, 23, 34

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

i like to ask for advise how to let this array [1,2,3,4] to become  12, 23, 34?

this initial is a number 1234,  i split them

```js
let sum
sum = String(this.numbers).split("").map(Number);
console.log('numbers set1', sum)
```

so from here it becomes [1,2,3,4]

how can i join/combine/concat then to become 12, 23, 34 respectively?

thank you very much for Hello World's guidance

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const num = 1234;
const result = String(num)
  .split("")
  .map((n, i, src) => (src.length !== i + 1 ? `${n}${src[i + 1]}` : null))
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(Number);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Dear Decpk,  thanks for your help,  i tested it and it achieved what was expected by my teacher.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to write simple algorithm to get pairs of those numbers. Try to traverse the string/list and insert the new values into another list.

Sudo code can be something like:
let's say you have arr with numbers [1,2,3,4]

```
for i = 1 to N:
 string sum = arr[i-1]+arr[i];
 list.push(sum)
```

Comment: This isn't javascript code. OP specifically tagged `javascript` tag.

Comment: @decpk I think giving direct answer isn't right way of learning in programming. Problem isn't hard and requires some brainstorming. So I wanted him to implement by himself :)

Comment: I totally agree with you, but It is totally based on the person who is learning because In the beginning I've learned by coping/debugging/understanding others code. Pseudocode didn't help me. 

Comment: Dear Mark and Decpk,  thanks for your replying,  im still new to javascript and what i was asking is just part of the whole answer which i needed,  with the clues, i think i can try to expand the codes,  yes, i will implement and improves the codes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4];
    var list=[];
    for(i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        let sum = parseInt(arr[i-1].toString()+arr[i].toString())
        list.push(sum)
    }
console.log(list);
```